# Is there a way to show all content in a jquery accordion (without scrollbars)

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

`Autoheight : false` seems to have no effect. Even if it did work it doesnt sound like its what I need since one section could be really long and the fololowing really short and I wouldnt want the two sections with the same height.

The div in which the content is displayed can be of variable height so I cannot use a fixed height. I have tried most of the options and none of them seem to have the effect I want but I think I am missig something as this sounds like it should be a common requirement since scollbars in the accordion look rather horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to explicitly set the Height and Width of the Acccordion to the content?  For example load the content into a hidden div and then get its dimensions.  Then resize the Accordion and load the contents to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line instead:

```
heightStyle: "content"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
autoheight : false
```

It is auto with a small **a**